# Using INSERT INTO with multiple value lookup field

Tags: vba

I have a macro that populates a form with a drop down list from an Access table and then asks users to select multiple items:

Code:

```
  With myconn
  .Open ("DATABASE")
  End With

Set dataRst = myconn.Execute("SELECT ID, Name FROM [TABLE IN DATABASE] ORDER BY Name;") 'WHERE variable = '" & x & "';")

Do While Not dataRst.EOF

cboVAR1.AddItem x, x
cboVAR1.Column(0, x) = dataRst!Name
cboVAR1.Column(1, x) = dataRst!ID

cboVAR2.AddItem x, x
cboVAR2.Column(0, x) = dataRst!Name
cboVAR2.Column(1, x) = dataRst!ID

x = x + 1
dataRst.MoveNext
Loop
```

The form I'm using looks like this:
[image: Form]

I then want to take these selections and add them to the an email:

```
Set myEmail = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
myEmail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

myEmail.To = Var1
myEmail.CC = Var2
```

And then update a new row into a new table with:

```
INSERT INTO [NEW TABLE] ([Variable 1], [Variable 2])
VALUES (VAR1, VAR2)
```

I'm able to populate the email, but whenever I try and update the NEW TABLE I get:

Run-Time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'VAR1 value1; VAR1 value2;'.

I've tried reading up on that error, but just can't figure out what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: might be missing the ` ' ` (single quotes) that should enclose text values?

Answer (score 0):

If that is your exact code you need to do something like this,

Also this is assuming that these two variables will always be a text value.

```
myEmail.To = VAR1
myEmail.CC = VAR2
str = "INSERT INTO [NEW TABLE] ([Variable 1], [Variable 2])" _
         & " VALUES ('" & VAR1 & "','" & VAR2 & "')"
```

Obviously, I have just added the `str` variable to demonstrate how the string for the insert statement needs to looks in VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried that but now am receiving: "Compile Error: Argument not optional". I also tried using sqlstr instead of str, but that gave me my original error. VAR1 and VAR2 will always be text values.

Comment: Using the above as a guide and enclosing in quotes and using sqlstr = I'm not getting the error: Run-time error'-2147467259 (80004005)' An INSERT INTO query cannot contain a muli-value field... I'm relatively new to VBA, is this correct? Is there another way to insert a multi-value field into a table?

Comment: @AaronPujanandez, what is the database you are using?

Comment: Access 2013. With tables linked to SharePoint lists.

Comment: @AaronPujanandez, try this , `Set dataRst = myconn.Execute("INSERT INTO [NEW TABLE] ([Variable 1], [Variable 2]) VALUES ('" & VAR1 & "','" & VAR2 & "')")`

Comment: Same error: An INSERT INTO query cannot contain a muli-value field... Thanks for the help! I'm thinking I'm going to have to rethink my approach.